# How to change replace inner text of xdmnode(SAXON)?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, saxon, xpath-2.0

How can we change inner text of a xdmnode?My requirement is to replace innertext of a xdmnode with a xpathvalue extracted from another xdmnode. It's easy while implementing xmldocument. Do any one have a clue to implement this in xdmnodes?

Answer (score 1):

Normally XPath and XQuery work on an inmutable tree so don't expect to find any setters on the default tree model. The usual approach with XQuery is to write a query that returns the changed tree.

As you mention `XmlDocument` and `InnerText`, I suppose you work with Saxon on the .NET platform. There you also have the option to write XPath 2 or 3 against a wrapped `XmlDocument` node and then to drop back to the MS .NET DOM API to manipulate a node with e.g. `InnerText`.

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/DocumentBuilder.html#Wrap(System.Xml.XmlDocument) allows you to wrap the document, then, once you have selected an `XdmNode` you can call https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XdmNode.html#getUnderlyingXmlNode() to access the `XmlNode` and set its `InnerText`.

Answer (score 1):

The XdmNode model is intended primarily for use with functional languages like XSLT and XQuery and is therefore designed to be immutable. However, there are implementations of XdmNode that wrap underlying node models (including Microsoft's XmlDocument), some of which are mutable, and there's nothing to stop you diving down and doing modifications using lower-level interfaces.